# Ubuntu on an Acer C7 Chromebook?

Tags: installation, laptop, chromebook

Has anyone succeeded in installing a plain vanilla Ubuntu (or other Linux distribution) install on the Acer C7 Chromebook? I am aware of the [ChrUbuntu](http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com/2012/04/chrubuntu-1204-now-with-double-bits.html) project but would prefer a plain vanilla Ubuntu install if possible. I am not sure how the special google firmware influences a standard Linux install?

Comment: Here you go, this should help! http://liliputing.com/2012/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-on-the-199-acer-c7-chromebook.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want to install Ubuntu on Chromebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643769/want-to-install-ubuntu-on-chromebook)

Comment: @Amolith Different hardware making both questions different and relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Chrubuntu IS a plain vanilla Ubuntu installation as far as I can tell after a couple of weeks of daily usage. I'm using it with the MATE desktop; I am not a big fan of Unity, but it runs very, very well. I've installed some pretty demanding games (Bastion, Portal, Half-Life 2), and they play at full speed. I did install video upgrades for the Sandy Bridge Celeron from the  ubuntu-x-swat PPA, and I have very few complaints about this $200 computer which did not come with a Windows tax.

Answer (score 1):

fyi: there is a fix for the problem of the internal mic not recording after the Ubuntu install; read the bug fix here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1093395

Comment: what's that have to do with the question? He wants a non ChrUbuntu way of installing ubuntu, not a fix for that bug

Answer (score 1):

I know this reply came a bit late, but if you're still looking to replace ChromeOS completely with plain vanilla Ubuntu, have a look at this article: http://johnlewis.ie/pre-built-coreboot-firmware-for-chromebooks/

Warning, this involves hardware hacking and will most certainly void your warranty. I've detailed my personal experience here: https://askubuntu.com/a/361561/97517