# Problems installing Crouton on a Chromebook

Tags: system-installation, keyboard, touchpad, chromebook, crouton

I'm trying to install Crouton and I'm not sure what went wrong so I'll list my problems below:

1. Touchpad stopped working right after it rebooted during developer mode.
2. I downloaded Crouton but it won't install. in the developer shell it says that I need a root password to mount encrypted roots, whatever that means.
3. Keyboard stopped working once I got to prob #2, so I can't put in the password even if I knew it.

I'm following the steps on this website: [How to Install Ubuntu on your Chromebook with Crouton](http://www.howtogeek.com/162120/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-chromebook-with-crouton/)

I'm using an Acer Chromebook 14

Please help

Also I'm still at the developer shell where it asks for the password. Haven't touched it

Comment: please fam need help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want to install Ubuntu on Chromebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643769/want-to-install-ubuntu-on-chromebook)

Answer (score 0):

Try test0000 as password . It should ask you to create a passphrase afterwards

Answer (score 0):

I recommend removing Chrome completely from the Chromebook rather than running a Chroot. It makes everything run faster and much smoother.

I'm seeing a lot of people, in questions like these, answer saying that you can't remove ChromeOS from a Chromebook due to Chrome custom BIOS not letting you. I want to clear that up and say ***you can.***

This tutorial-like answer is for installing the **full** version of Ubuntu to your Chromebook. It isn't a *version* of Ubuntu like Chrubuntu but the real, full-fledged, OS.

### How?

I installed [SeaBIOS](https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/) on my Chromebook and installed Ubuntu 17.04 from a flash drive, *however*, I think that SeaBIOS also allows you to install an OS from Jeltka (I'm not sure what that is and I didn't use it; I already had the flash drive made).

SeaBIOS boots from SSD by default but, as it's loading, you can tap `esc` and boot from any device listed. This lets you run a native OS as well as any other OS that is compatible with your hardware from a USB.

To replace Chrome's custom ROM and install different OSs, you have to first put your Chromebook into

### Developer Mode:

To invoke **Recovery** mode, at login screen, you hold down the `ESC` and `Refresh (F3)` keys and tap the `Power` button.

To enter **Dev-mode** you first invoke **Recovery**, and at the Recovery screen press `Ctrl-D` (there's no prompt - you have to know to do it). It will ask you to confirm, then reboot into **dev-mode**.

**Dev-mode** works the same as always: It will show the scary boot screen and you need to press `Ctrl-D` or wait 30 seconds to continue booting.

### Hardware

After this, you will need to bridge the write protect jumper ***with your chromebook off and preferably with the battery out!***

***NOTE***
This is where the write protect jumper is on a Parrot Chromebook (Acer C710); it will probably be located in a different place on your Chromebook, if it's a different model.
[image: 1]
That little white square at the end of the pink tab is the jumper (it's under a black tab that you'll have to peel off); you can probably bridge it with a bit of solder, if you want it permanent. I used a piece of aluminium foil.

### Software

Once you have done this, you'll need to reboot your Chromebook, open your browser, then press `ctrl+alt+t` to open the shell.

***[MAKE SURE YOU READ LEWIS'S SUPPORTED MODELS MATRIX](https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/)***

Once you have read the developer's [supported models matrix](https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/), you can run the following command in the Crosh shell **as a normal user *not* root**

### Command

```
cd;bash <(curl https://johnlewis.ie/flash_cb_fw.sh)
```

### Last Bit

Finally, follow the on-screen instructions *according to your model and what the matrix says it supports*.

Once you have done all of this, you will be able to install an OS from USB to your SSD, run an OS from live USB, *or,* now, again, I'm not sure how this works so you should do some research (I couldn't find much when I was looking), you can boot from payload which, I **think** install an operating system of your choice from the ones available.

### Note

On a C710 Chromebook, I know the touch pad won't work (I'm working on installing the Ubuntu-modified ChromeOS drivers) and neither will the brightness keys, volume, reload-page button, etc. I'm not sure what the issue is there yet, but I am working on it and, if you do what I've said here, and want the drivers/keyboard-fix-stuff, ping me and I'll edit those into the answer once I've figured it all out. I don't know what will/won't work on other models.

This will wipe everything on your computer so I recommend transferring any files you have to some cloud storage system or to a flashdrive or something.